# How to program a calculator to follow the order of operation?

Tags: python, math, calculator, equation, operation

I'm new to Python and I'm working on a calculator, it works fine with to numbers but when I input something like 4+3*3 the result is 21 instead of 13, so I want to know how to program my calculator to follow the correct order in which it has to calculate an equation.

```
operation = input('Enter equation: ').replace(" ", "")
num1 = ""
num2 = ""
operador = ""
op = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
for char in operation:
if char not in op:
    if operador == "":
        num1 = num1 + char
    else:
        num2 = num2 + char
else:
    if operador == "":
        operador = char
    else:
        if operador == "+":

            num1 = str(float(num1) + float(num2))
        elif operador == "-":
            num1 = str(float(num1) - float(num2))
        elif operador == "*":
            num1 = str(float(num1) * float(num2))
        elif operador == "/":
            num1 = str(float(num1) / float(num2))

        operador = char
        num2 = ""

if operador == "+":
 num1 = str(float(num1) + float(num2))

elif operador == "-":
 num1 = str(float(num1) - float(num2))
elif operador == "*":
 num1 = str(float(num1) * float(num2))
elif operador == "/":
 num1 = str(float(num1) / float(num2))

print(num1)
```

Comment: Have you tried something like the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)? It can handle different levels of operator precedence.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744788/calculator-expression-evaluator-prefix-vs-postfix-notation/63745670#63745670

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using a 'for' loop for the input string.

For the example input "4+3*3": first it gets the '4' then the '+' operator and all the other letter from the input string, which doesn't result the correct order of the computation.

Some tutorial for the for loop in python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

I would try some different approach, like first checking if the input string has '*' or '/' and then calculate with the other operators(of course if the input doesn't have '(' or ')' ).

Comment: Thank you i'm going to try that aproach

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).